# how to calculate the starting time and end time for apache camel router?

Tags: spring, apache-camel

i am trying to capture the start time and end time of the apache camel router.
We are using camel for messaging and we have implemented soap serviceand quartz are in camel router like below

```
public class BbdDmsBatchRoute extends RouteBuilder{



    @BeanInject
    private BbdImageProcessorBean bbdImageProcessorBean;

    @BeanInject
    private SwtDEAStockProcessorBean swtDEAStockProcessorBean;

    @Value("${bbd.batch.enabled}")
    private String isBatchEnabled;

    @Value("${bbd.dmsStockBatch.interval}")
    private String bbdDmsBatchInterval ;

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BbdDmsBatchRoute.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        //***********Batch Job to get BBD images**************//
                //  This Batch Job will run based on time given in properties file for "bbd.batch.interval" property (bbd.batch.interval=0+0+12+1/1+*+?+*)   
                LOG.info("BBD Batch Job Cron expression {}",bbdDmsBatchInterval);

                from("quartz2://STouchDmsBatch/bbdDailyJob?cron="+ bbdDmsBatchInterval)
                .choice()            
                 .when(simple(isBatchEnabled))
                    .doTry()
                    .bean(bbdImageProcessorBean, "bbdReRunDmsBatchInvocation") 
                    .split(bodyAs(List.class))                          //Split each object in list and process in parallel
                    //.executorServiceRef("executerRefProfile").parallelProcessing()                    
                    .to("direct:batchJobRouteUnitWork")
                    .end()
                    .endDoTry()
                    .doCatch(Exception.class)
                    .to("direct:BbdReRunError")
                    .end();


        }
}
```

i want to calculate startime when my quartz2:StouchDmsBatch gets triggered and endTime when the route get completed without any exception.

i red few examples, told to use camel interceptor, EventSupport and so on. 
i would like to know did anybody have implemented the same?
can somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this .. if you just want to capture current time at some point and then use it in your logging somewhere .. you can store the current time in a exchange property and then use it anywhere you like..

[How to time portions of an apache camel route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516718/how-to-time-portions-of-an-apache-camel-route/40522414#40522414)

Answer (score -1):

You can add this class as a bean. Then enable the events you are interested. You can then see how long each step takes.
http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html

Comment: @What?? Seriously.